# Graphically use other users' processes

Tags: windows-7, windows

A regular user logs out leaving some applications running. Then an administrator enters the system, and is able to terminate the former's processes.

But could he use said applications including their GUIs?

Comment: Logging out closes all programs. Did you mean "locks screen/workstation"?

Comment: Logging off doesn't kill a given user's processes...

Comment: On Windows NT it does, at least with all versions I've used.

Comment: You're entirely right. In addition (and at least by default), even by fast user switching, an admin won't be able to see other the users processes as much as they're actually running.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Given sufficient privileges (specifically *SeTcbPrivilege* which only `SYSTEM` account has), it is possible to connect to any session without a password.

If the system supports multiple sessions ("Fast user switching" and the like), the administrator can log in to their own account, then run **`psexec -si tscon OldSessionID`** and access the other user's session without having to unlock it.

(I have tested this on XP Pro, but I'm not sure if it works on Vista/7 which handle sessions *slightly* differently.)

To leave the user's session, just lock the screen again by using <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd>, or run `tsdiscon`.

Comment: Sounds awesome, will try it and leave feedback. Thanks

Comment: Jesus, it works! Thanks so much. Looks like that sysinternals site will be a close friend of mine from now on.

Comment: For future reference: The actual work is done by `tscon`, while the only thing `psexec` does is raise its privileges. Other useful commands are `shadow` (remotely control an *active* session), `qwinsta`, `rwinsta`/`logoff`, `msg`...

Answer (score 2):

The simple answer is no, admins can see the processes being run, but not the applications themselves.

However, an admin could change your password and log in as you.  Then they could see what you were doing.  This of course would become apparent when you tried to log in and your password was changed.